# In Powershell what is the email separator

Tags: powershell

I have a code in the azure PowerShell workflow runbook. And I have the following code

```
Send-MailMessage -smtpServer $SMTPServer -Credential $credential -Usessl -Port 587 -from $EmailFrom -to $EmailTo -subject $Subject -Body $Body
```

the EmailTo is

```
 $EmailTo = "xxx@abc.com;yyy@abc.com"
```

I get a

```
Send-MailMessage : An invalid character was found in the mail header: ';'.
```

At EventStopAlert:5 char:5

error...but if I add just one email, then it works.

So I wanted to know what the email separator is in PowerShell.

Comment: tried comma too.....gives the same error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if you suggested comma above will work. I have always done this by passing an array of addresses.

```
$to = @("Address1@company.com","Address2@company.com")

Send-MailMessage -to $to
```

Answer (score 2):

Please see `get-help Send-MailMessage`.

```
Send-MailMessage [-To] <String[]>
```

It's an array of strings.  Take your semi-colon or comma delimited list and split it into an array.

Something like this:

```
$EmailTo = ($toLine -split ';').Trim()
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be valid:

```
$EmailTo = 'xxx@abc.com','yyy@abc.com'
```